# .htaccess redirect is showing absolute path of the 404.php file. How to avoid that?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have main domain `xyz.com` and it's home folder is `/home/username/public_html/`

On the same server I also have subdomain `sub.xyz.com` and it's home folder is `/home/username/public_html/subfolder/`

I am creating a web site for subdomain and I'm trying to do some redirects using .htaccess file. I have placed 404.php file in subdomain's home directory. There is also .htaccess file for subdomain and .htpassword file too. For the purpose of this test I have renamed .htaccess file of the main domain and simplified version of my subdomain's .htaccess file looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\. /404.php [R=404,L]
```

When I write non-existing filename e.g. `sub.xyz.com/non.existing` the address in browser stays the same and I'm presented with the content of 404.php file. Fine.

But when I write existing filename e.g. `sub.xyz.com/.htpassword`, the address in browser change to this: `sub.xyz.com/home/username/public_html/subfolder/404.php` thus revealing my directory structure.

Oddly enough same happens when I write non-existing filename `sub.xyz.com/.htpasswords`, but everything is OK for non-existing filenames `sub.xyz.com/.htpasswor` & `sub.xyz.com/.htpassword1`

What should I do so that behaviour would be the same for existing & non-existing files?

Address should stay the same equally for all cases or change to sub.xyz.com/404.php equally for all cases.

Comment: Well, this is what you implemented! The `ErrorDocument` directive takes care of requests to those "non-existing files" and presents the output of that script. For "existing files" however that directive does not match, instead your `RewriteRule` matches, which _explicitly_ implements an external redirection to that script. An external redirection changes the URL visible in the browser, since it _redirects_ the browser.

Comment: Well, this wasn't answer in a sense what should I do, but it was an answer in a sense what I shouldn't do. It helped me to find the answer and understand syntax better. Tnx

Comment: True, this wasn't an answer, it wasn't an answer at all, which is why I did not post it as an answer, but as a comment. I did not explain what you shouldn't do, but what you _did_ . As to enable you to get forward yourself. Since this is _not_ a place to give you a snippet to copy and paste, but to make you understand what you are doing. Please note that you are expected to be able to use your tools yourself, that is a requirement to get help here. We are not here to do your work for you, but to help you solve your issues yourself.

Comment: Ask yourself this question: why did you implemtn that `RewriteRule`? What do you try to achieve with it?

Comment: Thanks again. As I said earlier your comment helped me to find the answer myself. So I upvoted it. What I also don't know is: do upvotes on comments have same value as the upvotes to answers, and should I write the answer now or leave it open?

Comment: Upvotes on comments just indicate that people agree, not more not less. No credit points are involved, if that is what you refer to. But that is irrelevant to me anyway. If you have a _true_ answer, then sure, go ahead and post it along with an explanation what you actually changed and more important why you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since @arkascha choose not to gave straightforward answer but to hint what should be changed, I'm going to write it down. Now, when I knew where exactly is the problem I have found in Apache documentation on page [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html) under "Forbidden" the answer to my question

> This example uses the "-" syntax for the rewrite target, which means that the requested URI is not modified.

So the proper .htaccess part look like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\. - [R=404,L]
```

So this way, URI stays the same and user is presented with the content of 404.php file, like I wanted.

**Another important notice:** example I have used is a bad one and I have moved file .htpassword bellow folder public_html, but it is useful for other files that you don't want to reveal their presence to malicious user

Comment: I fail to understand this answer: it still is completely unclear what you need that rewriting rule for at all... The rules matching patter matches any path that _staarts_ with a literal dot ("."). I doubt that will ever match...

Comment: I use it to hide all files without a name, so when I want something to be hidden i name it  ".config_file" or something similar

Comment: This appears a bit odd... Instead you should keep such files outside the portion of the server side file system which you publish via the http server or place them inside a common folder to which you block access by a single, robust and plausible "access denied" rule.

Comment: It is true that since I have moved password file bellow public_html folder I currently don't use that rule. The problem is that ISP of the domain that I currently work on is very untransparent about rules enforced on the domain. I have asked them and didn't get any useful answer. I can see that .htaccess or folder /inc are protected with empty .htaccess file. The thing is that I don't want to depend on them, since they changed configuration in the past without sending me a notice (and I can't change ISP either) so I want to protect files and folders by myself through .htaccess file.

Comment: ... so I also have following rule `RewriteRule ^inc(/.*)? - [R=404,L]`. I have tested it with another folder name and it performs as expected: URI stays the same and user get 404 no matter if the file/folder exists or not.

Comment: But you _can_ protect the files yourself as you insist. All I say is: don't rename the files but place them inside a protected folder. A folder which _you_ protect yourself by means of request rewriting.

Comment: Besides, all hosting providers I know offer file system space that is outside the portion that is published by the http server. But your's may be different.